# jQuery .get(), submitting values in/out of form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a bid to my php system using a get request ".get()".

I've been trying to interpret the documentation, and I feel like I have most of the steps correct.

Regardless, here is my html:

```
<div id="1001AIE0322921TTGOD" class="item">
    <input name="userbid" type="input" value="19.95"/>
    <input name="email-id" type="hidden" value="whatever@iwin.com" />
    <input type="button" class="submit-button" value="click"/>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var item = $('div').attr('id');
    var bid = $("input[name=userbid]").val();

    $('.submit-button').click(function(){
        $.get(
            "http://qwicksale.com/classes/insertbid.php",
            {
                item-id: item,
                email-id: email,
                userbid: bid
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Obviously my expected outcome is to be able to post the bid to the back end. I would use the form.serialize() thing, but I'm retrieving my item data from the id of the div.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That looks ok, are you having any specific problems?

Comment: You mind this ? `$.get("url", {}, function(data){alert(data);});`

Comment: can you add the div's id as a hidden input to your form... and thus be able to use the form serialize() method.

Comment: Are you sure you can put arbitrary mathematical operators in the middle of object literals like that without quoting? What's in your JS console?

Comment: Side note: Generally speaking, requests that make changes, like this one, should be done as a `post`, not a `get`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you mean the attribute selectors? Those only need to be quoted if they have a space in the value, though I prefer to always quote them.

Comment: @JasonP Doesn't work for me in Chrome; gives me an "Unexpected token `-`", although that's in the console.

Comment: OH, like `item-id` and `email-id`. I believe you are correct, those can't have a `-`.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the response from the server. You should have a callback function in there so you know the result of the AJAX call: `$.get("myUrl", { foo: "bar" }, callback);`

Comment: You can still use `serialize()`, as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading your question and several comments, I see a few issues, but no answer that encompasses all of the them:

This line:

```
var item = $('div').attr('id');
```

Gets the ID of the first div on the page, probably not the one you're looking for. Instead, do something like this:

```
var item = $(this).closest('.item').attr('id');
```

Second, object literals can't have a `-` in them. Change your object to this:

```
{
    'item-id': item,
    'email-id': email,
    userbid: bid
}
```

Third, it sounds like you are being restricted by the same origin policy. You can't do cross-domain ajax requests from the browser unless you are using JSONP or CORS.

Fourth, requests that make changes to data or **do** something should generally be `POST` requests, not `GET`.

Issues 2 and 3 should have shown up in your error console.

**Edit** One other big issue: You are grabbing the values to send when the page loads, so if someone changes them, the changes won't be sent to the server. Put the three lines that retrieve the values inside the click handler, before the ajax call.

Comment: +1, encapsulates most problems in a single answer (but skips the onready issue :)

Comment: I quoted the object literals, and put the file on the same domain, and switched to a POST request (changed my server accordingly).. still, it doesn't seem to be working.. I click the button and nothing happens - nothing in the console.

Comment: @Alpinestar22 Then start debugging, adding `console.log`s to see where execution is stopping, etc.

Comment: @Alpinestar22 Open the dev tools in your browser, refresh the page, and click the send button. Then check the error console and network tab for errors. If there aren't any, find the XHR request on the network tab and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton. I checked my variables with console.log - the email value was wrong (I was using the wrong name). It seems to be working as expected now. So, along with quoting the object literals, and putting my variables inside the click() function, It seems to be working. Much appreciated.

Comment: On a side question, for my knowledget @JasonP - what is 'this' referencing? Where the mouse is?

Comment: In a jQuery event handler, `this` is the DOM object that triggered the event. So in your case, `this` is the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You were retrieving the values of the inputs inside of your READY function which only get's called once when the page loads. You need to move those lines to your CLICK function so you get the current values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.submit-button').click(function(){
        var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
        var item = $('div').attr('id');
        var bid = $("input[name=userbid]").val();
        $.get(
            "http://qwicksale.com/classes/insertbid.php",
            {
                "item-id": item,
                "email-id": email,
                "userbid": bid
            }
        );
    });
});
```

**edit** quoting the data objects keys, for sanity.

Answer (score 1):

This solution gets the job done without having to skip `serialize()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submit-button').click(function (event) {
        var $item = $(this).closest('.item');
        var formData = $(':input', $item).serialize() + '&item-id=' + $item.attr('id');
        $.get('http://qwicksale.com/classes/insertbid.php', formData, function (response) {
            // Handle the response
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68W59/

Answer (score 0):

Dude, not sure about your error , but when i tried in fiddle i was getting like 
'Access Control ...'

here i have modified the changes [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6kxqH/1/)

```
$.getJSON(
            "http://qwicksale.com/classes/insertbid.php?item-id="+item+'&email-id='+email+'&userbid='+bid+"&format=json&callback=?",
            function(data) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

FYI

Getting error in 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'User_email' cannot be null' in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/qwicksale_com/classes/insertbid.php:47
in
insertbid.php:

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to submit the form to the server right?

If that is the case you'll want to use `$.post`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Also as other answers have pointed out your object isn't formatted correctly, so even if we did figure out if you really want a `post` or `get` neither will work.

```
{
    "item-id": item,
    "email-id": email,
    "userbid": bid
}
```

Comment: GET, POST, that's just the HTTP method. I'd *prefer* a POST for this, but why would that part matter?

Comment: Both will trigger a request to the server.  Since he did not state his intention for submitting the values to the server we cannot say which should be used.  If his intention is to change the state of the application than per the HTTP specification he should use post.

Comment: @DaveNewton Because if his server method is looking for `post` data it won't find it if he uses `get` on the client.

Comment: I am working through jsfiddle.. so I am using GET so I can post to my script on my server. It is to my understanding that I can't use POST for crossdomain requests?

Comment: @Jack Obviously... but that's making an assumption.

Comment: @Alpinestar22 You can't use `GET` either... unless you are using JSONP or CORS.

Comment: @DaveNewton If I've learned anything from answering jQuery questions it's that assumptions need to be made because some people are just learning and don't understand everything.

Comment: @Jack I prefer the opposite approach: making assumptions leads to incorrect and/or misleading answers. Instead, *seek clarification* so you can answer *correctly* instead of guessing and potentially obfuscating answers. YMMV.